# Can you change the "from" clause based on certain paramters? SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Im working in bigquery and with alot of google analytics data.

In the from clause when you work with this ga data, you can change the date range of the data within the name of the from clause. Example Gadata_2023*, gives you all data 2023, ga_data202301* gives you janurai data from 2023. you can specify it down to the day.

So what i was thinking was maybe there is a way to automate it so i only take yesterdays data within the from clause to minimize the cost of processing. Ive seen some similar things been done to where clauses.

The main reason im asking about this is because I wanted to append data to an existing table to minimize the processing data cost.
What i found was that it was the same amount as pulling the whole year. so if there is a better way to this please tell me that.

Comment: have a look at `_TABLE_SUFFIX` - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables